# Prevent swipe action in Switch button - Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to prevent toggle by swipe action in a `Switch` and only toggle when clicked on it using Compose.

```
val switchState = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
Switch(
    checked = switchState.value,
    enabled = true,
    onCheckedChange = { switchState.value = it }
)
```

Comment: This is not possible with default Switch composable but you can copy source code and do small modifications to meet your requirements. Most of the default composables are pretty straightforward